# How to Search and display a panel and its controls in a particular page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am developing a website using asp.net. Here am stuck due to some confusions.
In one of my page, there are number of panels available. Each panel has one label(State Name) and two text boxes. At top of the page, search bar **(drop down list)** is provided with State Names.

Now here the scenario is, If user selects a state from drop down then the particular panel with respective label(state name) should be searched.

**For Example**

Am having a State A, B and C are there in my Drop down list **(Search bar)** and at the same time am also having a three panels such as Panel x(State A as label name and two text boxes), Panel y(State B as label name and two text boxes), and Panel z(State C as label name and two text boxes) in Default.aspx page.

**Now I need, if user selects State A from drop down list then the particular panel(which label is having State A) should display with all controls**

"No connection with database"

Hope am not confusing. Any help would be more helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some one help this question to get answer. Am so stuck in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially keep all the panels visibility as false by

```
Panel.visible=false;
```

then check for the selected value of dropdown

```
if(dropdown.selectedItem.ToString()=="State A")
    Panelx.visible=true;
else if(dropdown.selectedItem.ToString()=="State B")
    Panely.visible=true;
else
    Panelz.visible=true;
```

and set the AutoPostBack property of dropdown to true and write the above code in dropdownSelectedIndexChange event
(hoping that your values are static)